# Syncing code to a label using P4Python

Tags: perforce, p4python

I am trying to sync code to a particular label in the depot using the Python script with help of Python API provided by Perforce.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What has the result been so far? Do you know the equivalent p4 sync command-line formulation that you wish to run?

Comment: yes, i have command line, something like p4 sync @labelname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
p4.run("sync", "...@[labelname]")
```

or the more idiomatic

```
p4.run_sync("...@[labelname]")
```

Comment: thanks for this. I am trying to search and read a labelname from the list of labelnames in the depot. Equivalent command line would be something like p4 labels -e * lname * where lname is a part of labelname. could you help please

Comment: Again, you could use `p4.run_labels("-e", "*[labelpattern]*")` and inspect the output (structured data). An alternative would be to use `for label in p4.iterate_labels()` and do your own filtering by `[labelpattern]` using regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks for the help!!